# GlassFish5 w/JDK8 under MacOS JDK11 install

Tags: java, macos, glassfish, java-11, glassfish-5

Need to run GlassFish5 on MacOS. Current version installed are JDK11.02 and JDK1.8.0_144.

```
>echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

>which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

>java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I have appended the last line in file `glassfish5/bin/asenv.bat` with
    `AS_JAVA=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home`

And I still get a NPE Exception when starting up GlassFish:

```
>asadmin start-domain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What am I missing?

Or is running GlassFish w/JDK 8 (u144) on MacOS with a JDK11 not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `AS_JAVA` variable in `asenv.bat`, you need to set `AS_JAVA` in `glassfish5/config/asenv.conf`.

`AS_JAVA=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home`